# How does modifiers(as in xmodmap) work under linux operating system?

Tags: linux, input, x11, keyboard-events, modifier

I learned that xmodmap has 8 modifiers, and I can add keysyms to modifiers. However, I am increasingly confused about modifiers. How do they work?

```
$ xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x94)
mod3      
mod4        Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  ISO_Level3_Shift (0x6c),  Mode_switch (0x85),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xmodmap, if I want to exchange Caps_Lock and Control key, what I am going to do is:

```
clear lock
clear control 

keycode 0x25 = Caps_Lock # 0x25 is keycode for Control_L originally
keycode 0x42 = Control_L # 0x42 is keycode for Caps_Lock originally

add lock = Caps_Lock
add control = Control_L Control_R
```

But I don't understand:
when I press left control key, keycode 0x25 will be generated and keysym Caps_Lock is generated. then it is done. Control key becomes caps lock key. why do I have to care about  modifiers?

And on my Ubuntu PC, I:

```
clear lock
clear control
```

Control key and caps lock key still work as expected. So my question is how does modifiers work? It seems modifiers do not matter at all.

Additional info:
if I :

```
clear shift
add control = Shift_L Shift_R
```

Shift_L and _R still works like a shift key, and `xev` still has 0x11 for keyboard state instead of 0x14.

control_L and _R key will make keyboard state 0x14.

Comment: You could use `xev`  to understand what is happenning

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, I am. `xevtest` is misinformation. It is xev.